Android Studio/IntelliJ not autocompleting classes in one package directory
I have an Android Studio/IntelliJ project. In one directory, autocompletion is working as expected in my Kotlin classes.
However, in another directory of the same project, no autocompletions are working. For example, I have:
package com.example.cupcake

class Foo {
    val foobar = 6
    val bleck = 
}

If I start to type foo it will offer foobar as a suggestion, as expected.
But in another package directory (with the package directive appropriately updated), it keeps giving unresolved reference until I type in the complete name foobar, at which point it's recognized and colored appropriately. This also happens for methods I have explicitly imported, such as org.junit.Assert.assertEquals. It won't recognize the function name assertEquals until it's fully entered.
Interestingly if it's a class instance and I start to type in a property name of that class, it does offer an autocompletion suggestion for it.
I checked Settings/General/Import and there are no autocompletion exclusions.
I tried closing the project, renaming the top-level directory, and opening it as a new project. I tried invalidating all the caches and restarting IntelliJ. Other projects work as expected.
What might be causing this?
This is Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 2 running on Windows 11.
